# Set version on a windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a windows service that is installed using a setup project. Things work fine but I would like to be able to set the version of the service as I do with the AssemblyVersion of my assemblies.

The only place where I have been able to see this version number is in the version column in the listing of applications in the add or remove applications dialogue.

Comment: Where would you be hoping to see this version number? I cannot see anywhere it is used in windows services explorer for any of my existing services.

Comment: That's correct I can't see the version number anywhere in the service explorer. The only place where I've seen this is in the listing of applications in the add/remove program window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. In the solution explorer highlight your setup project.
2. Then select your "Properties" tab. (not right click the project, this is counter intuitive)
3. Find version number at the bottom, when asked to change the product code, select yes.
4. That should be it.

Hope that helps.

Paul

Comment: Too easy... I'll probably start having the Properties tab open from now on. Thanks Paul!

Comment: +1: Just for working out what OP wanted. I was misled by him looking for version number in add/remove programs :S

Comment: @Jeep No problem, happy to help, that bloody properties tab has had me stumped before, even after I knew about it :)

Comment: @musefan I read your comment and was starting to wonder if I was right in my thinking but just tried to concentrate on the Setup project which I have experienced the same problem with in the past.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, As Paul said

1. In the solution explorer highlight your setup project.
2. Press **F4** or open "**Properties**" tab from **View** option of Menu of **VS**. (not by right clicking the project).
3. You can find version number at the bottom and other options like Product name etc.

I tried it and it worked.. :)