# Give Version number to a windows service C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, version, versioning

I have made a windows service. I want to assign a version number to it. I have already checked some other questions on SO about this ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582110/set-version-on-a-windows-service)). But in my project, there was no Properties file. So, I have done the following steps

- Right click the Project Name
- Clicked "Properties"
- Assigned version number under the category "Publish"
- Clicked "Publish Now"

After doing the above steps, a "Properties" folder has been created in my project, which contains `app.manifest` file. Even after compiling the service again, I cannot see the version number (version number is still `0.0.0.0`)

PS: This is the first time I am trying to do versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Properties AsemblyInfo.cs you can set version and all related this to your assembly

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("******")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("*********")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("*******")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("*******")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]



// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("3.0.0.37")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.0.0.37")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("*******")]
```

Comment: There is no "AsemblyInfo.cs" in my properties folder. Do I need to create "AsemblyInfo.cs" myself?